# How to use stat or bash to check whether FILENAME refers to a file

Tags: files, stat

Does the `stat` command offer, or does `bash` offer, a straightforward way to check whether `FILENAME` refers to a file rather than, say, a directory?

Using `bash` and `stat`, here is my ugly solution:

```
if RESPONSE="$(LC_ALL=C stat -c%F FILENAME)"\
 && [ "$RESPONSE" = 'regular file'\
 -o "$RESPONSE" = 'regular empty file' ]
then
    # do something ...
fi
```

See also [this related question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332296/18202)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-f` test will be true if the given name is the name of a regular file or a symbolic link to a regular file.  The `-h` test will be true if the given name is the name of a symbolic link.  This is documented in both `man test` (or `man [`), and in `help test` in a `bash` shell session.  Both tests are [standard tests](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) that any POSIX `test` and `[` utility would implement.

```bash
name=something

if [ -f "$name" ] && ! [ -h "$name" ]; then
    # "$name" refers to a regular file
fi
```

The same thing using `stat` on OpenBSD (the following bits of code also uses the standard `-e` test just to make sure the name exists in the filesystem before calling `stat`):

```sh
name=something

if [ -e "$name" ] && [ "$(stat -f %Hp "$name")" = "10" ]; then
    # "$name" refers to a regular file
fi
```

(a filetype of `10` indicates a regular file).

If using GNU `stat`:

```bash
name=something

if [ -e "$name" ] && [[ $(stat --printf=%F "$name") == "regular"*"file" ]]; then
    # "$name" refers to a regular file
fi
```

The pattern in this last test matches both the string `regular file` and `regular empty file`.

Answer (score 3):

A `stat` solution as asked for.

`stat --printf "%F" file-name`

see manual (extract below)

```
       -c  --format=FORMAT
              use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after each use of FORMAT

       --printf=FORMAT
              like  --format,  but interpret backslash escapes, and do not output a mandatory trailing newline;
              if you want a newline, include \n in FORMAT

The valid format sequences for files (without --file-system):

       %F     file type

GNU coreutils 8.30
```